# MongoRuby and Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Can anybody say me why this works in mongodb

```
db.sub_count.update({"subject":"petad","count":1},{$inc:{"count":1}})
```

But this doesn't work on ruby

```
sub_count.update({"subject" => "petad", "count"=> 1},{$inc => {"count" => 1}})
```

where I get the error

```
/lib/bson/bson_c.rb:24:in `serialize': keys must be strings or symbols (TypeError)
```

Comment: what's the value of your global variable $inc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be:

```
sub_count.update({...}, {"$inc" => {"count" => 1}}) # And not :$inc
```

`$inc` is not a valid symbol (or string) and that's why you see the error.

**Aside**: I'm not sure if this works: `:"$inc"` You can define a symbol this way but there is no mention in the [Ruby driver docs](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html) that a symbol can be used for the atomic operators and since I haven't tried it at any point, I'm not sure.